# How to detect button on which cell was exactly selected

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

Suppose that I have a custom `UITableViewCell` contains `UIButton` control. When the user presses the button it should present another view controller with the appropriate info according to which cell was chosen (to be more precise, I have an array of objects used to represent information in the `UITableView` and I want to transfer this info to the next view controller). The question is how can I detect button on which cell was exactly selected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find your answer in detail...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291427/uibutton-and-the-order-of-ibaction-and-segue/27291712#27291712

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this.. but the way of superView is no more available since iOS8. I am sharing a code which is working perfect in all iOS.

Write this selector on your cellForRow method

```
[cell.btnOnCell addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now write this method

```
-(void)btnAction: (UIButton *)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tblView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblView indexPathForRowAtPoint:currentTouchPosition];
    NSLog(@"%li",(long)indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: And what should I do then? Save the selected cell's info in the view controller's property and transfer it to another view controller in the `prepareForSegue` method? And why should I use `addTarget` instead of `@IBAction` method btw?

Comment: I've shared a code to find out which cell's button is clicked. Now Its all up to your requirement, what you want to do with this index path. If you don't want to write selector, IBAction will also work.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And in this case the next question is -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291427/uibutton-and-the-order-of-ibaction-and-segue

Comment: My detail answer to your question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291427/uibutton-and-the-order-of-ibaction-and-segue/27291712#27291712

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Insert below code in cellForRowAtIndexpath

```
[cell.yourbuttonName addTarget:self action:@selector(yourbuttonNamePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

paste the below code as separate method

```
- (void)yourbuttonNamePressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
CGPoint swipepoint = sender.center;
CGPoint rootViewPoint = [sender.superview convertPoint:swipepoint toView:self.goalsTable];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.goalsTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootViewPoint];
}
```

Comment: "ButtonClicked" action is in the `UITableViewCell` file, so I am unable to access `UITableView` here

Comment: remove your button clicked action from tableviewcell and add it in the above method that i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is that when you configure cell in CellForRowAtIndexPath there you need to set the cell.button.tag=100+indexPath.row.

```
-(void)btnClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
NSIndexPath* path= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag-100 inSection:0];
UITableViewCell*cell=(UITableViewCell *)[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
}
```

**NOTE**: you need to remove addTarget and buttonClicked implementation from UITableviewcell 
and in cellForRowAtIndexPath method addtarget to button and in this class implemnt buttonClicked Method.**

Comment: Why should I do `addTarget`? And what should I do then? Just present new controller? Could I use `prepareForSegue` btw?