# UIButton and the order of IBAction and segue

Tags: ios, uibutton, segue

Suppose that I have a `UIButton` control and I attached both the `@IBAction` method on the click and segue to it. Is it guaranteed that the click method will bed called before the segue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that yes but it is not clear somewhere.But what do you want to do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this, this will work perfect in your case..

In your first ViewController.h create a property to store indexPath

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSIndexPath *indexPath;
```

In your second ViewController.h create a property to store indexPath

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSIndexPath *indexPath;
```

Now in you first ViewController.m file

Forget IBAction for now, Write this selector in your cellForRow

```
[cell.btnOnCell addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Write this method

```
-(IBAction)btnAction: (UIButton *)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tblView];
    self.indexPath = [self.tblView indexPathForRowAtPoint:currentTouchPosition];
    NSLog(@"%li",(long)self.indexPath.row);

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdToYourSecondVC" sender:self];
}
```

No write this method (this method will call after your performSegueWithIdentifier)

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
 {
     if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueIdToYourSecondVC"])
     {
         // Get reference to the destination view controller
         YourSecondViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
         vc.indexPath=self.indexPath;

     }
 }
```

Thanks..hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't like to programmatically call such functions like `performSegueWithIdentifier` and prefer to do it via storyboard